# getopts called in function not picking up flags

Tags: bash, getopts

I have the following script that I call from my `.bash_profile`:

```
# Set directories based on current path
__set_dirs() {
    currdir=`pwd`
    if [[ ${currdir} =~ "\/path\/to\/main\/(.*)\/working\/([a-z]+)(/?.*)" ]]
    then
        ws=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        subdirs=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        stgdir=${ts}/${ws}/STAGING${subdirs}
    else
        echo "${currdir} is not a workspace"
        stgdir=""
    fi
}

# Update local version with staging version
upd() {
    __set_dirs
    if [[ -n ${stgdir} ]]
    then
        __overwrite=0
        while getopts "o" opt
        do
            case $opt in
                o)
                    __overwrite=1
                    ;;
                \?)
                    echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
                    ;;
            esac
        done

        echo "Updating ${currdir} with latest from ${stgdir}..."
        if [ ${__overwrite} -eq 0 ]
        then
            update -r ${stgdir} ${currdir}
        else
            echo "Overwriting all local changes!"
            update -r -w ${stgdir} ${currdir}
        fi
    fi
    unset __overwrite
}
```

When I execute

```
> upd -o
```

The flag is completely ignored--I never see the message "Overwriting all local changes!". Have I missed something somewhere?

**UPDATE:** It *does* work, but only the *first* time I run the script. From the second time on, the flag gets ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All right, figured it out:

After rifling through the [man page for `getopts`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/getopts/), I found this tidbit (emphasis mine):

> Each time it is invoked, getopts places...the index of the next argument to be
>   processed into the variable OPTIND.  OPTIND is initialized to 1 each
>   time the shell or a shell script is invoked.... **The shell does not
>   reset OPTIND automatically; it must be manually reset between 
>   multiple calls to getopts within the same shell invocation if a new set of parameters is to be used.**

Since I only run the script once from by .bashrc, `OPTIND` only gets initialized once. The first time I run the function, everything's hunky dory. The second time on, `OPTIND` is set to 2 and `getopts` doesn't find anything there, so it moves on.

Armed with this knowledge, I modified `upd()` to reset `OPTIND` to 1:

```
upd() {
    __set_dirs
    if [[ -n ${stgdir} ]]
    then
         __overwrite=0
         OPTIND=1
         while getopts "o" opt
...
```

That fixed it. `OPTIND`: more important than you'd think.

Answer (score 2):

`getopts` acts on the parameters passed into your function, so in your case you have to call the `upd()` function with `"$@"`, to pass all the command line parameters into your function.

eg:

```
test() {
  while getopts "o" opt; do
    case $opt in
    o)
      echo o
    ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
    esac
  done
}
test # this wont work as $1, $2, ... are not set
test $@ # this will work as you pass along the command line parameters
```

**Edit**

I overlooked the `.bashrc` part, if I source the example above, into my running shell, then `test -o` works as expected.

Comment: Don't forget to double-quote `$@` to handle arguments with whitespaces: `test "$@"` (although in this particular case it doesn't make any difference)

Comment: See, that works for me, too. That's why I posted all the code--I'm wondering if I'm breaking it somehow with some other part of the function.